# Why do they use an ObjectId and a Number in the Mongoose Population example?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, population

In [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) example, they create `personSchema` using `ObjectId` to reference the `Story` and this I understand. But then in `storySchema` why don't they do the same to reference the person?

Or the inverse: why using ObjectId instead of Number in Person?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema

var personSchema = Schema({
  _id     : Number,
  name    : String,
  age     : Number,
  stories : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Story' }]
});

var storySchema = Schema({
  _creator : { type: Number, ref: 'Person' },
  title    : String,
  fans     : [{ type: Number, ref: 'Person' }]
});

var Story  = mongoose.model('Story', storySchema);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', personSchema);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type of reference has to be the same as the referenced schema's `_id` property.

In case of `personSchema` it's a `Number`.

`storySchema` on the other hand, has the `_id` field assigned automatically by mongoose - it's not specified in parameters for the schema constructor.

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an _id field by default if one is not passed into the Schema constructor. The type assiged is an ObjectId to coincide with MongoDBs default behavior

Comment: so if they did not specify the `_id` in `personSchema` they could have  used `ObjectId` in `_creator` and `fans`? is there a particular reason why they preferred using a Number?

Comment: @fusio maybe they wanted to avoid the chicken-egg situation by setting their own id on one of the collections - that way they don't have to wait until mongo inserts the document to reference it from another. That way you only need books inserted before setting up the references. Can't say for sure though.

Comment: They probably just did it so that it shows the example in case someone ever does change the _id.  You can reference the _id without saving an object.

Comment: You're not alone - that Mongoose example confused me too (3 hours of searching later.) A clearer example would have been to return the newly saved `person` doc (assigned to the `aaron` variable) then reference the newly generated `_id` that way, which would have meant that the `personSchema._id` field could have been handled by Mongo rather than set manually. Does this sound logical or am I barking up the wrong tree here?